# Error in Join query with pagination for Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination, oracle10g

I'm executing this query in SqlDeveloper targeting a database in Oracle 10g:

```
select P1.FIELD1, P1.COD from 
(select P1.FIELD1, P1.COD, row_number() 
over (order by P1.FIELD1) r from 
SCHEMA1.P2 
INNER JOIN SCHEMA1.P1 on SCHEMA1.P1.COD=P2.FIELD2) 
where P1.FIELD_11 = 'VALUE1' and r between 6 and 10;
```

And Oracle returns:

```
Error SQL: ORA-00904: "P1"."FIELD_11": invalid identifier
```

I tried:

```
select SCHEMA1.P1.FIELD1, SCHEMA1.P1.COD from 
(select SCHEMA1.P1.FIELD1, SCHEMA1.P1.COD, row_number() 
over (order by SCHEMA1.P1.FIELD1) r from 
SCHEMA1.P2 
INNER JOIN SCHEMA1.P1 on SCHEMA1.P1.COD=SCHEMA1.P2.FIELD2) 
where SCHEMA1.P1.FIELD_11 = 'VALUE1' and r between 6 and 10;
```

And I got the same error:

```
ORA-00904: "SCHEMA1"."P1"."FIELD_11": invalid identifier
```

I cannot find examples of select clauses with inner join and pagination for Oracle 10g, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have messed the query with aliases which makes it confusing.use shorter aliases instead of whole `schema.table.column` everywhere

```
SELECT p.field1,
       p.cod
FROM   (SELECT p1.field1,
               p1.cod,
           p1.field_11,
               row_number()
                 over (
                   ORDER BY p1.field1) r
        FROM   schema1.p2 p2
               inner join schema1.p1 p1
                       ON p1.cod = p2.field2) p
WHERE  p.field_11 = 'VALUE1'
       AND r BETWEEN 6 AND 10;
```